# PDO can't insert new record into Access database, but can read and delete in same connection

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc

I have a problem. I have a ms Access DB files, which I have to read and modify (delete and insert records). I use PDO odbc. And I have strange situation where I can read and delete but I cann't insert new records in DB with same connection. **I have already checked insert string in ms Access and it works perfectly**. 
Here php code:

```
<?php

$path = getcwd() . "\\tempFolder\\MSDB.mdb";
$con = "odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$path; Uid=; Pwd=;";
try
{
    $db = new PDO($con);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //READ
    $cmd = "SELECT * FROM temp_HEADER WHERE [LINE-ID]='101'";
    $result = $db->prepare($cmd);
    $result->execute();
    $result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result); echo "<br/>";

    //DELETE
    $cmd = "DELETE FROM temp_HEADER WHERE [LINE-ID]='101'";
    $result = $db->prepare($cmd);
    $result->execute();
    echo "DELETE OK<br/>";

    //INSERT
    $cmd = "INSERT INTO temp_HEADER ([LINE-ID], PLANE, DISPLAY, X, Y, Z, LENGTH, SURF, ROCK, VARIA, LTYPE, NAME) "
    . "VALUES('101', '100', '', 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, '', 1, 'LINE', 'TEMP')";
    $result = $db->prepare($cmd);
    $result->execute();    
    echo "INSERT OK";

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

This code get me following result:

```
Array ( [LINE-ID] => 101 [PLANE] => 100 [DISPLAY] => [X] => 100.0 [Y] => 100.0 [Z] => 100.0 [LENGTH] => 0.0 [SURF] => 0.0 [ROCK] => [VAR] => 1 [LTYPE] => LINE [NAME] => TEMP [Ind] => 1041 ) 
DELETE OK
SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 39 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access]Invalid character value for cast specification (null) (SQLExecute[39] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)
```

What is wrong with this?

p.s.: I tested this one script in several computers and some of them show all results well, but another - got error in insert command.

EDIT: Add type of fields:

```
LINE-ID - Text<br/>
PLANE - Text<br/>
DISPLAY - Text<br/>
X - Number(Double)<br/>
Y - Number(Double)<br/>
Z - Number(Double)<br/>
LENGTH - Number(Double)<br/>
SURF - Number(Double)<br/>
ROCK - Text<br/>
VARIA - Number(Long Integer)<br/>
LTYPE - Text<br/>
NAME - Text<br/>
Ind - AutoNumber(Long Integer)<br/>
```

EDIT: I have just written the same code in C# and everything is OK (I could read, delete and insert). I used the same sql queries as here, but I used oleDB. In this case I think that something wrong with odbc with pdo in php. Couldn't someone tell me how can I connect to DB via oleDB in php because fast search didn't get any result? 

EDIT: I tried to use code with COM (OleDB). I repeated the same task with read, delete and insert. What I got:

```
variant Object 
DELETE OK
Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine
Description: type Mismatch
```

EDIT: 
I created mdb file and simple script with read, delete and insert function and put it [here](http://wikisend.com/download/831448/temp.7z). This code doesn't work for me. If you can run it without problem, please, write down the version of your driver. I think the problem in driver. In my case, I've already tried to change ODBC shortcut from system32 into sysWOW64, but nothing changes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am unable to recreate your issue. I created a  test .mdb with the required table, copied and pasted your PDO code into a .php file, and it ran fine under PHP 5.4.17. Despite what your sample code says, you wouldn't happen to be trying to insert Unicode characters into the database, would you?

Comment: yes I have text in unicode. this DB is from another software, which I want top modify for my solutions. I tried another DB and everything work with PDO, but with this kind of files - I have these troubles.

Comment: The .mdb file that I used when testing my OLEDB code (in my answer below) is available for download [here](http://wikisend.com/download/373008/MSDB.zip). Try it instead of your MSDB.mdb and see if it works better for you.

Comment: the problem is that this kind of files I get from another program, which I have to modify for something. I understand that these mdb-s are little bit strange, but I have to use them. Of cause, today's morning I created my own mdb-file and to make select, delete, update and insert command and all of them are executed well.

Comment: Can you take a copy of one of those "strange" .mdb files, delete all the records from all of the tables, and then upload that "empty shell" database to a site like [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com) so we could try to recreate your issue?

Comment: I created en empty db and also add php file with SQL-queries. So you can try to solve my problem. File in 7z: http://wikisend.com/download/831448/temp.7z

Comment: I just downloaded your 7z file. When I ran your "temp.php" script against your copy of the "GD_TEMP.mdb" database it worked fine for me. The last line of output was "INSERT OK" and the new row was inserted correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem which I don't know how to solve. I've already written this one in p.s. above. On Friday, I tested it in four computers, and 2 of them work well, and another 2 - got error. And this is a problem, I don't know how to make those computers (and my home's computer) to work correctly with insert command. I know, that one of friday's computer I destroied when I delete driver from ODBC manager in User DSN tab. Before I did it everything worked well, but after - it didn't work. I tried to repair but I couldn't. I have win 7 64bit, and that code doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have already changed drivers filder from system32 into sysWOW64, but nothing to happen. I tried several drivers from Microsoft web, and I got the same situation - it didn't work for me

Comment: I've just checked UPDATE command - and  it works. only INSERT doesn't work

Comment: @Gord Thompson - what version of MS Office do you have? And OS?

Comment: I used my old 32-bit Vista machine with Office 2010 on it.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, I installed Office 2010 but no changes. It still doesn't work. BTW, at work our administrator has two pcs. One of them applied INSERT command with that simple script, but another one - no. We spent the whole day together to try to solve the problem, but no result. Stupid file. I think I will make this part of project in C# (as daemon), because I have lack of time to find out any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in preparing if you are going to harcode the value.

On the other hand it is a risk you are taking as you can make a mistake and data type won't match.

It looks like you are inserting coordinates, for instance a blank string ('') will not convert to float.

Try to prepare this query properly:

```
$cmd = "INSERT INTO 
        temp_HEADER (`[LINE-ID]`, `PLANE`, `DISPLAY`, 
                     `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `LENGTH`, `SURF`, 
                     `ROCK`, `VARIA`, `LTYPE`, `NAME`) "
    . "VALUES(  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$result = $db->prepare($cmd);
$success = $result->execute(array('101', '100', '', 
                                  100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 
                                  '', 1, 'LINE', 'TEMP'));    
if($success){
    echo "INSERT OK";
}else{
    echo "INSERT FAIL";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335), `var` is a reserved word in MS Access.

One of your variables is called `var`, so you are getting a syntax error.  Wrap the name in square braces.

EDIT:

The error suggests that there is a type conflict between one of the columns and the value you are providing.  In any case, the over-riding idea is the same.  The connection is fine.  The SQL has syntax errors.

Comment: I made shorter string only for here place. In original var... word

Answer (score 0):

What type is the "Display" field.  You seems to be inserting it into the database, yet the print out says its a two dimensional array

Comment: I added types of fields above

Answer (score 0):

> how can I connect to DB via oleDB in php

To perform the INSERT via OLEDB you would use something like this

```php
<?php
// this code requires the following php.ini directive:
//
// extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

$path = getcwd() . "\\tempFolder\\MSDB.mdb";
$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
$con->Open(
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" .
        "Data Source=$path");

$cmd = "INSERT INTO temp_HEADER ([LINE-ID], PLANE, DISPLAY, X, Y, Z, LENGTH, SURF, ROCK, VARIA, LTYPE, NAME) "
    . "VALUES('101', '100', '', 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, '', 1, 'LINE', 'TEMP')";       

$con->Execute($cmd);

$con->Close();
```

If you are dealing with Unicode text (as you mention in the comments to the question) then I strongly suggest that you abandon the PDO_ODBC approach because it is doomed. PHP and Access ODBC do *not* play well together when Unicode characters are involved.